# Windows 7 application issue - only appears in taskbar

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have an issue where a program that runs fine under windows xp has stopped working with windows 7.  The application appears to start fine then disappears with only the taskbar icon remaining.  If you hover over the taskbar icon you can see the application and it kind of looks correct but selecting it does nothing.  I cannot seem to get the application to actually appear.  Has anyone experienced anything like this and is aware of any possible solutions?

Recent builds have worked with windows 7 in the past and I don't believe any significant changes were made before this issue arrived.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be the program is running but somewhere off screen. Shift-right-click the taskbar button and select "Move." Press the arrow keys to begin the move, then move your mouse to attach the movement to the mouse cursor. See if that brings the app to the primary monitor.

If not, you may have an incompatibility issue which will require more research/investigation.

Comment: this worked! also once it was moved onto the screen when the program is restarted it no longer hides, so I would imagine its just some configuration that is wack - and I will look into that.

Comment: This can happen with programs that are not "aware" of multiple monitors; also with programs that write invalid location data when they are closed while minimized, etc. (Thus, they reopen at some coordinate that is off screen.)

Comment: Thank you. I had the same issue in Windows 8. Your method helps

Answer (score 0):

Holding down the Windows key and the letter P at the same time will allow you to change your projector settings.  Select the "Duplicate" option.  As mentioned above, this usually occurs when you typically use a dual monitor but switch to a single monitor.